# How to attach newly created .xlsx file to record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, caxlsx

```
class MyLog < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :xlsx_file
end
```

I create .xlsx file as email attachments:

```
xlsx = render_to_string layout: false, template: "dir/template"
xlsx_base64 = Base64.encode64(xlsx)
attachment = {mime_type: Mime[:xlsx], content: xlsx_base64, encoding: 'base64'}
attachments["file.xlsx"] = attachment
```

And also I want add this file to MyLog table as attachment:

```
MyLog.create(
  xlsx_file: xlsx
)
```

But xlsx is a string and it's not working. In the usual example attachable file came from file_field tag with ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile class and it's working. How can I attach my newly created with calsx .xlsx file to my record?

Comment: create a temp file, write the xlsx string to it, attach the temp file

Comment: @dbugger Like this: `t = Tempfile.new("test_temp")
t.write(xlsx)

xlsx_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
    tempfile: t, 
    filename: "file.xlsx"
 )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to accomplish this without using an uploaded file is the `.attach` function ([docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects)).

Example:

```rb
xlsx = render_to_string layout: false, template: "dir/template"
log = MyLog.create
log.xlsx_file.attach(io: StringIO.new(xlsx), filename: 'file.xlsx', content_type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```

You could also replace `StringIO.new(string_content)` with `File.open(filename)` if you were reading from the filesystem.